# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars When running Keras Conv1D with CSV file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm very new to Deep Learning with Keras. I'm trying to run a CNN model on a CSV file, and it supposes to be a regression problem. My CSV file look like the following.
[image]

Currently, I'm trying to run the following code.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, Flatten
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import time
import gc
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

gc.collect()
df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\wilso\\python\\datasets\\paper revision short term.csv')
df = shuffle(df)
x = [e for e in list(df.columns.values) if e not in ['TTI','EST','_TYPE_','Date','date','day_month']]
y = 'TTI'
y = df['TTI'].values
x=df[x].values
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1)
dense_layers=[0,1,2]
layer_sizes=[32, 64, 128]
conv_layers=[1,2,3]

for dense_layer in dense_layers:
    for layer_size in layer_sizes:
        for conv_layer in conv_layers:
            NAME="{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer, layer_size, dense_layer, int(time.time()))
            tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=f"log_tti\\{NAME}")
            print(NAME)
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Conv1D(layer_sizes, 2, activation="relu", input_shape=(93,1)))
            for i in range(conv_layer-1):
                model.add(Conv1D(layer_sizes, 2, activation="relu"))
            model.add(Flatten())
            
            for i in range(dense_layer):
                model.add(Dense(layer_sizes), activation="relu")
                
            model.add(Dense(1))
            model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
            model.fit(x, y,
                      batch_size=32,
                      epochs=10,
                      validation_split=0.3,
                      callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

However, I got the following traceback `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`, and it looks like the traceback is caused by this line `model.add(Conv1D(layer_sizes, 2, activation="relu", input_shape=(93,1)))`. If I remove my for loops the code will be working perfectly, but with the for loop, it will show the posted traceback. Does anyone know why is that? Thanks a lot for your great help and support.

Sincerely

Wilson

Comment: Hello, I have a doubt ... you are looping through layers " for layer_size in layer_sizes "...so don't you think you should use **layer_size**  inside Conv1D ...you have used **layer_sizes**

Comment: @Shweta Sharma  thanks a lot for finding my careless mistake. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I am writing this in the answer section coz in comment box i cannot add the code snippets, so..

**First thing** as i already mentioned in the comment that you have used layer_sizes instead of layer_size in Conv1D inside the loop

```
model.add(Conv1D(layer_sizes, 2, activation="relu", input_shape=(93,1)))
```

**Second thing** , you have used activation='relu' inside model.add()

```
model.add(Dense(layer_sizes), activation="relu")
```

which is wrong , it should be inside Dense() function like below

```
model.add(Dense(layer_sizes, activation="relu"))
```

After running the loops, you will get the following architecture

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, 2, activation="relu", input_shape=(93,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x, y,), batch_size=32,epochs=10,validation_split=0.3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, 2, activation="relu", input_shape=(93,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(32, 2, activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x, y,), batch_size=32,epochs=10,validation_split=0.3)

.... and so on till...

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(128, 2, activation="relu", input_shape=(93,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 2, activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 2, activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x, y,), batch_size=32,epochs=10,validation_split=0.3)
```

**every time you are calling the loops, you are creating a new sequential model** by calling following method

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(layer_sizes, 2, activation="relu", input_shape=(93,1)))
```

with that you are also calling the model.compile and model.fit again and again. As far  as I know , you should define the architecture once and then fit your model and that might be the reason that after removing the loops your code is working fine as you mentioned in the question.

These layers should be called only one time

```
model = Sequential()
model.compile()
model.fit()
```

I suggest you keep above lines out of any of the loops.

**Final thing**, you have triple-nested loops plus two loops inside it, it is not a good practice. Avoid nested loops as far as possible for the sake of time complexity.